# Display data from models in website

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I want to display latest data entered from models to the website.

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    service_code = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def Latest(return):
    latest_services = Service.objects.order_by('service_name')
```

index.html

```
{{ service_name }}
Latest Services Goes here
```

When I run the code nothing is displayed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the queryset:

```
<ul>
    {% for service in latest_services %}
        <li>{{ service.service_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Anyway, if you want to display the latest entries, you should add a new field to your model with the date. For example:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    service_code = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)
```

And then in your query:

```
latest_services = Service.objects.order_by('created_on')
```

Comment: It was just an example. What name do you suggest?

Comment: @NikhilShirsath ok, so mark it as acepted to close your question. Thanks ;)